# How to get document uri from online sharepoint url?

Tags: php, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office365, uri

I have a web application to show list of folders and documents in my site and guest users can manage them in the dashboard.

I want to get a document uri so I could open the document with client app when I click a document from the list.

(A document name will be shown as `a` html tag with `href`)

The most of documents have `webUrl` to open Sharepoint online if I get list of documents using Graph API.

The `webUrl` looks like:

(`docx` example)

`https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx%xx&file=Document.docx&action=default&mobileredirect=true`

But I want to get the downloadable link like this:

`https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/Shared%20Documents/SomeFolder/Document.docx`

Then I can attach `prefix` like `ms-word:ofe|u|` to every link of `docx` documents to open with client app.

How can I implement this?

And I want to know if it is the best choice when I generate the document uri from the `path` and `name`?

[image]

Comment: Are you still looking for help here?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I implemented this using parent folder `webUrl` and `name`. So I succeeded to get the correct url.

Comment: Glad to here that your issue was resolved :)-

Answer (score 0):

Try this endpoint:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answering to my question. Btw, can I get the document list inside `{item-id}`?

Comment: And actually, I get the list of documents using `{folder-id}` and path like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{folder-id}:/{path-to-relative}:/children`. In this case, can I use `folder-id` to get what I want? I use `folder-id` from database.

Comment: What do you mean get the document list inside {item-id}?

Comment: I mean what to use after `{item-id}` like `https://graph.microsoft.com/.../{item-id}/{relative-to-path}/children`. Is this possible?